# VBA; Runtime Error 1004, cant define this variable?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I just joined here. Since I am pretty new top programming with VBA or programming in general, I look amost everything up. But I can't seem to find the issue with my code here.. so i got sheets for each month in excel (index 4, 6-16 (index 5 is a data page, i messed that up lol)), and I want to remove come cell contents on each page. i try this by doing this:

```
'x is defined earlier
Dim mon As Integer
For mon = 6 To 16

    With Worksheets(mon)
        .Range("H6:I37").ClearContents
        .Range("Y6:Z37").ClearContents
        .Range("P42") = 0
    End With


   For x = 6 To 37

    If IsError(Cells(x, 16)) Then
            Cells(x, 16).ClearContents
        Else
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1)) Then
            Cells(x, 16).ClearContents
        Else
    End If

Next x

Next mon
```

But in:

```
For mon = 6 To 16
```

it spits "runtime error 104" and I really dont know why.

//edit1

So i added an array:

```
Dim monarray
monarray = Array(Januar, Februar, März, April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August, September, Oktober, November, Dezember)
```

(German month names)

so.. I dont actually know how to use this now!? I just know that this could be easier

//edit 2

I got the array working, trying to figure out how to use the array's index (0-11) in my for loop. at this stage i think i can do it by my own, i will keep it updated if i dont.

Comment: Comment all the code within the loop and try and run it, just to confirm that the issue is with the mon variable. I would have thought it more likely to error if you attempt to reference a worksheet that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I tried something else, which i came up with as i read your comment: I did this: With Worksheets(4)  instead of With Worksheets(mon). So it seems that it cannot handle "mon"...

Comment: I still suspect your worksheet indexing. Do you have 16 worksheets, and they are not other kinds of sheets?

Comment: Using numbers passed to `Worksheets` collection is not recommended unless you're confident. When you pass *number*, you refer to sheet's index in said collection. Not surprisingly, this can be not the sheet you need or not a sheet at all. It's better to create array with sheets' names and iterate over it.

Comment: @L.Sibum If you still suspect that mon is the issue then try renaming the variable to confirm this.

Comment: so... february is indexed as 6, march as 7 and so on, until december on 16. only january is on 4, but i handeled that one different anyways. and if i understood correctly i can create an array with "Jan", "Feb", etc. and these can have numbers assigned to them (jan=1 for ex.)?

Comment: If you decide to pursue the array of worksheet names method, you will have to decide whether to stay with a standard zero-based 1-D array, a non-standard one-based 1-D array or a 2-D array. I recommend the  standard zero-based 1-D array and cycle from LBound to UBound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it. The problem was the "mon" variable, but not the variable itself, but the name of the pages, since VBA seems to fail with " ä , ö , ü " (UTF.8?) I just got a Workaround to rename these letters to " ae, oe, ue ", then its working fine. Thanks for the help with the "Array" Thing, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about worksheets indexes?
I tried your code w/o

```
With Worksheets(mon)
    .Range("H6:I37").ClearContents
    .Range("Y6:Z37").ClearContents
    .Range("P42") = 0
End With
```

and it worked without errors..

And Worksheets Indexes is not equal to numbers after word Sheet in Project Explorer

Comment: well i actually tested for all indexes, with msgbox(Worksheet(*sheetname*).Index) since i did not find another way so find out the indexes lol...